# PHP not clearing RAM when finished

Tags: php, memory, ram

Below is the code I'm trying to finish to view logs on our PBX.  It runs fine, sorts through the log files, displays all the data, etc.  The problem is that once it's done, it keeps a large amount of data (several hundred MB) in memory.  I need it cleared out when it's done but can't figure out how.  If it's run a couple of times it sucks all of the RAM from the server and we start getting errors.  Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Call Search</title>
<body>

<?php
function getBetween($var1, $var2, $pool)
{
        $temp1 = strpos($pool, $var1) + strlen($var1);
        $result = substr($pool, $temp1, strlen($pool));
        $dd=strpos($result, $var2);
        if($dd == 0){$dd = strlen($result);}
        return substr($result, 0, $dd);
}

if(!isset($_POST['phonenum']) && !isset($_POST['WantedCallID']))
{
        echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';
            echo '<h4>Please enter the number you wish to search for...</h4><input     type="text" name="phonenum">';
    echo '<input type="submit" value="Go">';
    echo '</form>';
}

else if(isset($_POST['WantedCallID']))
{
   $counter = 0;
   $logfile="calllog";
   while (file_exists("/var/log/".$logfile))
   {
      if($counter==0){$logfile="calllog";}
      else{$logfile="callog.".$counter;}
      $path = "/var/log/".$logfile;
      $logtoarray = file($path);
      foreach ($logtoarray as $linenumber => $line)
      {
         if(strpos($line, "[".$_POST['WantedCallID']."]") !== false){echo $line."    <br>";}
      }
   $counter++;
   }
}

else
{
   $counter = 0;
   $logfile="calllog";
   $arrayCounter = 0;
   while (file_exists("/var/log/".$logfile))
   {
      if($counter == 0){$logfile = "calllog";}
      else{$logfile="calllog.".$counter;}
      $path = "/var/log/".$logfile;
      if(file_exists($path))
      {
         $logtoarray = file($path);
         $oldCallId = "";
         $currentCallId = "";
         foreach ($logtoarray as $linenumber => $line)
         {
             if(strpos($line, $_POST['phonenum']) !== false && strpos($line, "VERBOSE[") !== false)
             {
                    $currentCallId = getBetween("VERBOSE[", "]", $line);
                if($currentCallId !== $oldCallId)
                {
                   $callIdArray[$arrayCounter] = "Date: ".substr($line, 0, 22)." Call ID:".$currentCallId."\n";
                   echo "Date: ".substr($line, 0, 22)." Call ID:".$currentCallId."<br>";
               $oldCallId = $currentCallId;
            }
        }
        $arrayCounter++;
     }
  }
  else{break;}
  $counter++;
   }
   echo '<form action="test.php" method="post">';
   echo '<h4>Please enter the call ID you wish to search for...</h4><input type="text" name="WantedCallID">';
   echo '<input type="submit" value="Go">';
   echo '</form>';
}

$variables = array_keys(get_defined_vars());
foreach($variables as $variable) {
    unset(${"$variable"});
}
unset($callIdArray);
?>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What Alister said in his answer is correct, however there is another factor to this: your use of `file()` on what I assume is a fairly large log file. This is where your memory bloat starts, and you could probably reduce your memory footprint *dramatically* by using `fopen()`/`fgets()` and iterating through the file in manageable chunks rather than loading the entire file into memory at once.

Comment: Yes, the files are usually very large and very verbose.  We'll work on switching how we call the file.  For now we've adjusted the 'MaxRequestsPerChild' setting from 4000 to 1000, but that feels like we're just skirting around the issue rather than dealing with it head-on.  It also isn't clearing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a simple modification to your code that will read the logfiles one line at a time rather than reading the entire file into memory.

```
while (file_exists("/var/log/".$logfile))
{
    if($counter == 0){$logfile = "calllog";}
    else{$logfile="calllog.".$counter;}
    $path = "/var/log/".$logfile;
    if(file_exists($path))
    {
        $fh = fopen($path, 'r'); //change
        $linenumber = 0; //addition
        $oldCallId = "";
        $currentCallId = "";
        while( $line = fgets($fh) ) //change
        {
            $linenumber++; //addition
            if(strpos($line, $_POST['phonenum']) !== false && strpos($line, "VERBOSE[") !== false)
            {
                $currentCallId = getBetween("VERBOSE[", "]", $line);
                if($currentCallId !== $oldCallId)
                {
                    $callIdArray[$arrayCounter] = "Date: ".substr($line, 0, 22)." Call ID:".$currentCallId."\n";
                    echo "Date: ".substr($line, 0, 22)." Call ID:".$currentCallId."<br>";
                    $oldCallId = $currentCallId;
                }
            }
            $arrayCounter++;
        }
        fclose($fh); //addition
    }
}
```

Comment: Very helpful, thank you.  Do you suppose we need the section at the end that unsets the variables, then?

Comment: Unless there's more that happens after the end of what you've posted, it's never needed. PHP will unset variables and release memory on its own, it's the apache worker [inside of which mod_php is running] that's the culprit in not actually releasing the memory back to the system.

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have cleared the problem.  I'll post back if we have any other issues with this.

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to presume that you run this script through an Apache server. This is a fairly common problem, though I've more often seen it from resizing images.

Once an Apache child (the process that runs PHP) has had the amount of memory it, or more usually, PHP, increased because of a lot of data being used, it doesn't have a method to return the memory to the OS.

Instead, each child-process has the `MaxRequestsPerChild` setting. This might be set to `0` - never restart. If the inflating memory size is a problem, then setting this to a few hundred, or thousand, might be useful. After that many requests, the apache child is restarted, and so all the memory captured si returned to the OS, and a new child is spun up if needed. While the requests might take a little longer when the process is being restarted, the freeing of memory would be more useful.

Comment: We've dropped it from 4000 to 1000.  At any one time TOP only shows less than 10 '/usr/sbin/httpd' processes.  Not sure if that's any indication of how many are running.  We've dropped it as far as 40 and it doesn't clear it out either.